# MySQL - Multiply column by value depending on that column

Tags: mysql, sql, linqpad

How can I write this.. I have table 'Company' with a column 'Size'. The size references enums. I need to display the average company size as alias AS 'AverageEstimatedCompanySize' by substituting column 'Size' when column 'Size' is:

```
1 = 15
2 = 30
3 = 50
4 = 100
5 = 250
```

In other words, my table shows company size as either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. While 1 is actually a company size of 15.

This is all part of a bigger query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS 'Total # of Opps', AVG(Size*?) AS 'AverageEstimatedCompanySize'
FROM persontable AS POJT INNER JOIN opportunity
ON POJT.ID = opportunity.id
WHERE opportunity.TimeStamp >= '2012-01-01' AND opportunity.TimeStamp <= '2012-12-31' AND POJT.JobTitleID IN 
    (SELECT Id
    FROM job
    WHERE CategoryID IN 
        (SELECT id
        FROM job_category
        WHERE name IN ('Sc', 'Ma', 'Co', 'En', 'Tr')))
```

Comment: It depends on your application. For small number of choices simple CASE WHEN block could sufficient. Most of the time some kind lookup table is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something solvable with a [case statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). The following is untested but should point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS 'Total # of Opps', 
    AVG(
        CASE Size
            WHEN 1 THEN 15
            WHEN 2 THEN 30
            WHEN 3 THEN 50
            WHEN 4 THEN 100
            WHEN 5 THEN 250
        END
    ) AS 'AverageEstimatedCompanySize'
FROM persontable AS POJT INNER JOIN opportunity
ON POJT.ID = opportunity.id
WHERE opportunity.TimeStamp >= '2012-01-01' AND opportunity.TimeStamp <= '2012-12-31' AND POJT.JobTitleID IN 
    (SELECT Id
    FROM job
    WHERE CategoryID IN 
        (SELECT id
        FROM job_category
        WHERE name IN ('Sc', 'Ma', 'Co', 'En', 'Tr')))
```

Comment: These seemed to work, but when I add an additional WHERE clause, i.e. WHERE Opp.CompType IN (0,5), and compare it to a substituted WHERE clase, i.e. WHERE Opp.CompType IN (1,2,3,4,6), the Average Company Size remains the same?  Which leads me to believe that this CASE clause is taking ALL company sizes, not just the ones that fall under the existing WHERE clause (and sub queries)? - Confirmed, this takes every company size, not just the ones that fall under the where clause

Comment: Where are you applying the where clause? Are you sure its placement is actually applying the filtering the way you want? Perhaps edit your question to include the additional clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that one approach might be to modify the query to `JOIN` to the `Company` table appropriately (that's something you'll need to work out), and then modify the `AVG` statement:

```
... AVG(CASE `Size`
        WHEN 1 THEN 15
        WHEN 2 THEN 30
        WHEN 3 THEN 50
        WHEN 4 THEN 100
        WHEN 5 THEN 250 END) AS 'AverageEstimatedCompanySize'
```

where `Size` is from the `Company` table.

Now, a more dynamic approach would be to create a new field, or even a new table, that maps those sizes and just `JOIN` the `Company` table and say the new table in the query and just grab the appropriate field per row then. That would get rid of the `CASE` statement.